# Accessing array index variable from bash shell script loop?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

I want to access the array index variable while looping thru an array in my bash shell script.

myscript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
AR=('foo' 'bar' 'baz' 'bat')
for i in ${AR[*]}; do
  echo $i
done
```

The result of the above script is:

```
foo
bar
baz
bat
```

The result I seek is:

```
0
1
2
3
```

How do I alter my script to achieve this?

Comment: Also note that you basically never want `"${array[*]}"` instead of `"${array[@]}"`. Using `*` instead of `@` more or less treats it as a string instead of an array.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can do this using *List of array keys*. From the `bash` man page:

> `${!name[@]}`
>   `${!name[*]}`
>
> **List of array keys**.  If name is an array variable, expands to the list of array indices (keys) assigned in  name.  If name is not an array, expands to `0` if name is set and null otherwise.  When `@` is used and the expansion appears within double quotes, each key expands to a separate word.

For your example:

```
#!/bin/bash
AR=('foo' 'bar' 'baz' 'bat')
for i in "${!AR[@]}"; do
  printf '${AR[%s]}=%s\n' "$i" "${AR[i]}"
done
```

This results in:

```
${AR[0]}=foo
${AR[1]}=bar
${AR[2]}=baz
${AR[3]}=bat
```

Note that this also work for non-successive indexes:

```
#!/bin/bash
AR=([3]='foo' [5]='bar' [25]='baz' [7]='bat')
for i in "${!AR[@]}"; do
  printf '${AR[%s]}=%s\n' "$i" "${AR[i]}"
done
```

This results in:

```
${AR[3]}=foo
${AR[5]}=bar
${AR[7]}=bat
${AR[25]}=baz
```

Comment: Although this answer accomplishes the desired outcome, it is unnecessarily obfuscated by the printf statement. For example: `printf "$i=(${AR[i]})\n"` or `echo "$i=(${ARi]})"` both give a little extra by showing how to get key & var but strictly speaking `echo "$i"` would have answered the OP. The rest is "bash fu" :)

Comment: Why is it not possible: `a=(1 2);echo ${a[0]} # result: 1`?

Comment: @dimmech, I disagree. I think the `printf` example here is really useful too. It quickly helps orient a C or C++ programmer to how to use `printf` in `bash`, when one is already familiar with `printf`. I'm grateful to see this here. It gives me more value from this one answer.

Comment: I really enjoyed this answer. When I first saw it I was annoyed by the extra syntax and format touches, but later after these inevitably became essential I came to appreciate the wonderfully concise exposition here.

Comment: @dimmech, see [Why is printf better than echo?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803), `echo` should not be used for arbitrary data.

Answer (score 20):

Additional to jordanm's answer you can also do a `C` like loop in `bash`:

```
for ((idx=0; idx<${#array[@]}; ++idx)); do
    echo "$idx" "${array[idx]}"
done
```

Comment: Only if it was not a sparse array...

Answer (score 7):

Show indexes and values in same time (this script worked for me)

```
ARRAY=( "engineer " "CEO" "doctor" "teacher" )

for i in "${!ARRAY[@]}"
do
      echo " index---------------content"
      echo " $i                  ${ARRAY[$i]}"
done
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that your answer seems to reiterate what was already stated in the accepted answer. You may want to consider expanding it so that the difference to that answer becomes more visible; otherwise it would be best paced as a comment to that answer (once you have sufficient reputation).

Comment: @AdminBee His answer is simplified version of the accepted answer, and it's very easy to understand. I find it more helpful than the accepted one for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can  do something like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
AR=('foo' 'bar' 'baz' 'bat')
length=${#AR[@]}
for (( i = 0; i < length; i++ )); do
  echo "$i"
done
```

output:

```
0
1
2
3
```

Comment: What does this say that  [pfnuesel’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/278502/80216#278504)  doesn’t already say?

Comment: I may be mistaken but does pfnuesels answer not re-evaluate the array length on each iteration?