# Spaces in Filenames "breaks" filename scripting

Tags: wildcards

Terdon's Example 3 from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/612718/182280:

3. Select all files except those whose names end in `.sh` or `.jkl`

   ```bsh
   $ shopt -s extglob nullglob
   $ files=(!(*.sh|*.jkl))
   $ echo "${files[@]}"
   file.abc file.ABC file.def file.ghi
   ```

The challenge is a space in the file causes failures in the script:

```
for f in ${files[*]}  #https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/278502/182280
do
 echo "Processing $f file... "
done
```

For example, the space in the file `fi le1.jkl` "breaks" the file when processed by the script and returns:

```
 processing `fi` file...
 processing `le1.jkl` file...
```

What can be done to ensure that spaces do not "break" the file name?

Comments that serve to clarify the context / questions are appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See [the comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278502/accessing-array-index-variable-from-bash-shell-script-loop#comment484159_278502) on the question the loop came from: you should use `"${files[@]}"` instead of `${files[*]}`. This will ensure that each entry in the array is quoted correctly, and processed as a whole by `for`:

```
for f in "${files[@]}"
do
 echo "Processing $f file... "
done
```

See [the Bash manual section on arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html) for details:

> Any element of an array may be referenced using `${name[subscript]}`. The braces are required to avoid conflicts with the shell’s filename expansion operators. If the *subscript* is ‘`@`’ or ‘`*`’, the word expands to all members of the array name. These subscripts differ only when the word appears within double quotes. If the word is double-quoted, `${name[*]}` expands to a single word with the value of each array member separated by the first character of the `IFS` variable, and `${name[@]}` expands each element of name to a separate word.

See also [What is the difference between $* and $@?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41571/86440)